# Android. 2D game development

Tags: android

I would like to start developing a 2D game for Android, but i haven't got the slightest clue where to start. For instance, how are the Angry Birds games developed? I'm guessing it's a 2D engine or something?

Can anyone shed some light on the matter? Anything is appreciated as i have zero ideas on where to look first.

Comment: I've been doing this for about 30 minutes, and i thought of trying to ask here. I'm a real noob at develping games in general, haven't tried it before, haven't even looked around to find some info about the matter.

Comment: You might be interested in the book, "Android Arcade Game App: A Real World Project - Case Study Approach"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android 2D game development without an engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311841/android-2d-game-development-without-an-engine)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recommend LIBGDX

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/index.html

Open source, java, cross-platform, good support for Open-GL, lot's of examples and a good community.

Comment: Second that, i also use LibGdx its great.

Answer (score 13):

I've used AndEngine extensively and I really like it BUT

2D games - unless you have something really, really complicated in-mind (lots of physics and collision detection), I'd recommend you consider creating them in plain old HTML (HTML5, to be specific).

Why?

Because HTML5 works pretty-much everywhere and there are some really decent toolkits for making more complex stuff (including level editors and basic physics stuff).

Moreover, you can convert HTML5 into Apps for both Android, iOS and other platforms - e.g. your game will work pretty much everywhere with minimal extra effort. Using tools like Cordova(phonegap) even allows you to access things like cameras and tilt sensors in Apps created from your HTML5 code (Dolphin Browser on Android even allows those apps to run in the browser!)

If you do want fancier stuff, Corona is pretty decent and easy to learn and cross-platform too - and Andengine is great if you're happy to be stuck on Android!

Comment: everywhere  I can read to move to OpenGL for performance and you suggests to move to WebView, javascript? how much FPS has that scene? or how much SPF (Second Per Frame) need to draw a particle effect, what do you do with Garbage collector?

Comment: It would have been helpful, if you could add a reference to an opensource 2D game (basic) with HTML5. That will take out fear.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, Angry Birds was developed on its own 2D engine. I recommend to look at these engines:

[Corona SDK - really simple crossplatform(!) engine. Nice one to start.](http://www.coronalabs.com/)

[AndEngine - havent any type of documentation, but there are a lot of references and useful extensions, including Multiplayer. Good community](http://www.andengine.org/)

Marmalade (AirPlay SDK) - really powerful, but complex engine. Many hits were made on it

Also you can use Unity3D with 2D extension. Its awesome engine.

Good luck with your beginnings ;)

Comment: note that Angry Birds used box2d physics library too .. so not everything was from scratch

Answer (score 7):

Persnally, To Get started with your first 2D game, Don't straight away start with a Game Engine or 2D Frameworks.

Here's a Game that I developed with just the bitmap manipulation logic and a java thread to run the game.

[Parachute Penguins](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.positivesthinking.parachutepenguinsfree)

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.positivesthinking.parachutepenguinsfree

1. Create a Java thread that serves as a game loop.
2. Make use of SurfaceView and manipulate bitmaps and with onClickListeners you can achieve a simple 2D game.

Go for Game Engine and Frameworks once you are comfortable with it.

Comment: The links are broken :(

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend AndEngine. They have a really good forum plus their example code is pretty much self explanatory.

If you're looking for a headstart, follow this [tutorial](http://jimmaru.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/andengine-simple-android-game-tutorial/).

Go for AndEngine!

Answer (score 2):

[Felgo](https://felgo.com/) (felgo.com) offers several tutorials for any skill level. It's a cross-platform 2D game engine.
There is already an [open-source Angry Birds](https://github.com/FelgoSDK/FlappyBird) clone that was made with Felgo.
It also also comes with ready-to-use game templates for the most successful game genres like tower defense, platform games or puzzle games and provides reusable components for handling multiple display resolutions & aspect ratios, animations, particles, physics, multi-touch, gestures, pathfinding and more to prototype and build games within days  [API reference](https://felgo.com/doc/felgo-group.html).

Answer (score 1):

It is all well documented!

Try here, this helped me loads: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/06/android-game-development-tutorials.html

Comment: And will i be able to, for instance, develop games like these: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=au.com.phil.mine&feature=more_from_developer ??

Comment: designing a good game involves an extensive amount of creative juice. It is definitely not as simple as tackling a reference app for example. The resources available will give you the power to create games like that, hence the simple answer is 'yes'. There are visual tools (just search android 2d opengl on Google!) but the most powerful way is always go back to ADT and Eclipse :)

Answer (score 1):

I already answered similar question in another post: [Android 2D game development without an engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311841/android-2d-game-development-without-an-engine)

I posted a tutorial at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PnnHGCKrIzw

Assuming that you are familiar with Java, Eclipse (or similar compiler), Google API, etc. Here are the steps to build a full-blown 2D Android game:

1. Use drawable-nodpi for sprite images (gives sprite size consistency
   across screen densities and sizes)
2. Use different layouts to support various screen sizes (e.g.
   layout-large, layout-xlarge, etc...)
3. Use TranslateAnimation and ObjectAnimator to animate sprite movements across screen
4. Use math to figure out sprites collision (e.g. screen coordinates
   and sprite location etc.)
5. Use handlers and condition statements to control the game events

You can test the outcome of following the above guide to developing a 2D Android game by checking out the game Yum Yum Pow available on Google Play. The free limited version is available also on Google Play and can be downloaded at:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wildroid.yum.yum.pow.limited

Comment: the youtube link is not a tutorial, it's an ad