# Which game framework is easy to develop 2D game app in android?

Tags: android, game-engine

I am new to Android Game Development and want to start with 2D game, 
I want to know which game engines/frameworks are good for beginner level ?
 so that i can start easy simple game development in 2D.

Comment: This question belongs to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android. 2D game development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11817789/android-2d-game-development)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend following two:

1. [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/)
2. [LibGdx](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/)

Comment: Thanks rokonoid for reply, i tried both of above engines but they are not easy, as i am beginner.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Unity3d for this, so you have the option to make 3D as well.

http://unity3d.com/

Plenty of tutorials, assets to buy and a huge forum for tons of information.

Br / Henric

Comment: Is it a free/opensource framework?

Comment: Yes it's a free complete game engine. There are however Pro version for specific end plattforms, but that is not required. So it's free ! :D

Comment: cool, which programming language?

Comment: JavaScript, C# and Boo.